# How to call a constructor in c#

Tags: c#

Okay. I am trying to grasp constructors. I want to name this employee a Stormtrooper. But it doesn't seem to call it. I don't know if I am not reading constructors correctly or what but here is what I have

Any help would be appreciated. This is a very noob question I realize.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication297
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee s = new Employee(name);
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
        public Employee(string name)
        {
            name = Stormtrooper;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What that Stormtrooper is? Shouldn't it be "Stormtrooper" , a string?

Comment: Isn't that code a little short to be a stormtrooper? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `string` to the constructor, like this:

```
Employee s = new Employee("Stormtrooper");
```

Also, it is generally a bad idea, because it is confusing to people reading/maintaining your code to call a class member variable and a parameter of the constructor the same thing (`name` in this instance). Instead use the property value `Name`, like this:

```
public Employee(string name)
{
    Name = Stormtrooper;
}
```

Note: Many times you will see an underscore (`_`) or some other prefix (like `my`) on class members variables, like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
    public Employee(string name)
    {
        _name = Stormtrooper;
    }
}
```

Again, this generally makes it easier to quickly discern variables from property names from constructor parameters.

Comment: I see those underscores in the text book and I thought it was an author preference. Thanks for letting me know other programmers use it. This site truly helps me.

Comment: @Azzamean - Great, glad it helped. Good luck with your code.

Comment: You might as well use an auto-implemented property with a private setter. e.g. `public string Name { get; private set; }`

Comment: @DanielMann - agreed, but I was trying not to muddy the water with automatic properties with automatic private backing fields, the OP will get to that concept in due time. :-)

Answer (score 7):

in your constructor you're setting the local variable to `StormTrooper` (which isn't valid, as it's not declared any where. If you want it to be a string it needs to be enclosed in quotes, ie `"StormTrooper"`)

It should be this:

```
public Employee(string name)
{
      this.name = name;
}
```

The `this` keyword represents the instance of the class, and then setting the private variable `name` to the variable passed in named `name`

I normally name my private variables like so `private string _name`, so I can have a constructor like this:

```
public Employee(string name)
{
      _name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to send a string into Employee.

You never defined name in this code

```
Employee s = new Employee(name);
```

So instead try

```
String name = "Stormtrooper";
Employee s = new Employee(name);
```

Alternatively you can send the string directorly without creating a variable. If you're just constructing the class there is no need to initialise and store a variable.

```
Employee s = new Employee("Stormtrooper");
```

Also the fix on your actual constructor thanks to PostMan

```
public Employee(string name)
{
this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an official post on the Microsoft site about constructors - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx This will help you with the right way to use constructors as well as choose an appropriate constructor